# Laravel Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar

Tags: html, jquery, laravel

Deseo guardar una solicitud y a la vez con la misma ID guardar el detalle que de articulos que viene con ella.

```
  public function store(Request $request){
       $this->solicitud->save();
     foreach ($request->descripcion as $data ) {
      $detalle              = new Detalle();
      $detalle->cantidad = Input::get('cantidad');
      $detalle->descripcion = Input::get('descripcion');
      $this->solicitud->detalles()->save($detalle);

      }}
```

modelo Detalle

```
  protected $fillable=[ 'cantidad','descripcion','solicitud_id']; 
public function something()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Solicitud::class, 'solicitud_id');
   }
```

Modelo Solicitud

```
 protected $fillable=['titulo','fundamento','estado','slug','departamento_id','user_id'];
    public function detalles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Detalle::class, 'solicitud_id');
    }
}

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                         <thead>
                           <tr>
                             <th style="width:50px" scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                             <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                             <th></th>

                           </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                           <tr>
                             <td><input type="text" name="cantidad[]" placeholder="Cantidad" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="descripcion[]" placeholder="Descripcion" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                             <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Agregar + </button></td>

                           </tr>


                         </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <script
              src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

                          <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var i=1;
   $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text"name="cantidad[]" placeholder="Cantidad" class="form-control name_list" /><td><input type="text"name="descripcion[]" placeholder="Descripcion" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td></tr>');
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
   });

});
</script>
                        </html>
```

Me tira este error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array,
>   integer given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyect\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
>   on line 681

Espero poder haberme explicado bien. Saludos

Comment: ¿qué te aparece en el log de Laravel?

Comment: aqui una foto de un dd https://imgur.com/a/nAjQ3